# Why doesn't the Java garbage collector collect garbage?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm playing with a horrifying data structure which basically is a tree, and each node stores references to its children in a `HashMap` object. I'm having troubles freeing memory whenever I need to get rid of the root and all its subtrees except one, by setting this latter subtree as the new root. I thought it might be some bug in my data structure, maybe some reference that I forgot to be there, so nothing becomes eligible for garbage collection. But I wanted to try something much simpler first, and implemented the following test:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyNode {
        MyNode next;
        int somedata;

        public MyNode(MyNode n) {
            next = n;
            somedata = 0;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            MyNode p = new MyNode(null);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
                MyNode n = new MyNode(p);
                p = n;
            }
            while (p!=null) {
                MyNode p1 = p.next;
                p.next = null;
                p = p1;
            }
            in.readLine();
        }
}
```

When main reaches `in.readline()`, I can see in htop that the process still has 250MB or so allocated for itself, and nothing gets freed. I obviously first tried to simply do

```
p = null;
```

instead of the while loop. But it didn't work so I came up with the previous code.

Comment: Be careful - the amount of memory allocated to the process is **not** the same as the amount of memory being used for objects.  Most processes will not return memory back to the OS after it's been allocated to it, so even if the garbage collector did run, you would not necessarily see it reflected by the total memory allocated to the process.

Comment: Apply option `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` at the Java command line to use the concurrent collector. Otherwise I think HotSpot only triggers collections on allocations.

Comment: using HTOP is definitely the wrong way to measure the memory usage of a java task, You need to use a profiler- if you're using JDK 1.6 or higher then VisualVM comes with the JDK

Comment: Well I'm using HTOP because I'm interested in the actual memory that my program uses. But I think I got the point, probably Java isn't the best tool to do such an alloc/free job

Comment: Lorenzo, if you know in advance how much memory you're really going to need, then simply constrain Java's max heap to that size. That will force the GC to reclaim memory more ambitiously. You can be absolutely sure the GC is not going to allow an Out of Memory condition if there is reclaimable memory on the heap.

Comment: @Lorenxo Stella Most other languages behave the same. e.g. there's only very simple cases where memory can be given back to the OS in a C program when you use free()/malloc(). It normally doesn't matter much though, if the OS need memory for something else, it'll page out unused memory of the processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear - are you actually getting OutOfMemoryErrors? What are you trying to solve? There are a few reasons you are seeing the behavior manifested in your test case:

1. Garbage isn't collected the moment something is no longer reachable from a GC root - it simply becomes eligible for garbage collection. GC typically is only triggered when there is an allocation failure. Since you aren't actually allocating anymore memory in your loop that nulls out the references, it is entirely possible the GC just hasn't run yet.
2. Even when garbage is collected, the memory in the heap is typically not returned to the OS - so looking at it from the perspective of the OS will not yield an accurate answer. Using VisualVM or tools like jmap and jhat would be the best way to figure out what is actually still on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of the garbage collector is complex, and different garbage collectors can use fundamentally different methods. You can't expect garbage to be instantly reclaimed, even if you explicitly
invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before.

htop is not the best way to measure memory utilization by JVM. It keeps showing high mark.
VM also likes to keep its heap allocated as high as seen.

Might I suggest using visualgc or jconsole to track or jps and jpstat that ship with JVM.
http://java.sun.com/performance/jvmstat/#Tools

Also, you have a loop that creates lots of objects quickly, so gc might now have time to kick in.
System.gc is not guaranteed to actually get executed. It is a hint, but it usually works.

Take a look also at this post about Java heap utilization:
http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/lim/how-to-get-details-on-jvms-heap-utilization-10609

Answer (score -4):

You can manually call garbage collection once in 10000 loops using the code

```
System.gc();
```

However there are some side-effects such as extra cpu time used by garbage collector.

Comment: This is actually not recommended. You can halt the entire VM for a few seconds with that.

Comment: Actually JVM decides when to service this call. It is not mandatory that garbage collector gets called the moment it is invoked. So it is safe in a sense. But I agree it is a bad programming practise.

Comment: @user1559260 It is not mandatory, but unless you specify `-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent`, HotSpot *does* halt all threads on a call to `gc()`.

Comment: @user1559260 Here you are wrong. The Javadoc is clear in stating that "When control returns from the method call, the virtual machine has made its best effort to recycle all discarded objects." It is a synchronous call.

Comment: you mean while I'm setting all the references to null in the while-loop? I tried calling System.gc() once at the end of the loop. Nothing. Why would it do anything if I call it every 10k loops?

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk That link is interesting. The option seems to go against the Javadoc statement. Even though we can agree that "best effort" is not exactly a binding term.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk & MarkoTopolnik : Any alternatives to resolve this other than increasing heap size of JVM or coding differently? How do we free up memory then?

Comment: @Marko - immediately prior to that statement in the System.gc javadoc, it states: "... gc method suggests that the Java Virtual Maching expend effort toward recycling ...".  As stated by others here, "best effort" is subject to specific JVM/GC.

Comment: @LorenzoStella - Calling System.gc() in each iteration would just halt your application. gc() halts the running application to collect complete heap info and free up memory. So pausing every 10k loops seemed a good idea. But experts here suggest alternative solutions. Its up to you.

Comment: @RichardSitze That's just about what I have said myself in the comment above yours.

Comment: @Marko, sorry, missed that - apparently I was too busy reviewing javadoc to go back and look for newer comments :-)