# Garbage Collector doesn't seem to work sometimes

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

After reading [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F324499%2Fjava-still-uses-system-memory-after-deallocation-of-objects-and-garbage-collecti&ei=6KkAVcboDMiqU7zMgYgN&usg=AFQjCNGfAyDDk-XlExBg2ma4U5-D7fTHhw&bvm=bv.87920726,d.d24&cad=rja) && [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1567979%2Fhow-to-free-memory-in-java&ei=6KkAVcboDMiqU7zMgYgN&usg=AFQjCNFd4DqDh-WrRhgf_D-Amx6D3rpQ0g&bvm=bv.87920726,d.d24&cad=rja) I have been recommended to use C/C++ which have nice functions for memory allocation.

**Example**:
I have an app that makes 5000 JMenuItems (I don't need JTable). The memory goes up to 400 MB. When I delete all of them the memory goes (380--390) MB and I wait 2-3 minutes.

Why do I need the Garbage Collector and not a free() method when it doesn't deallocate memory as needed? Also, no memory leaks exist as far I know, and I use Java 1.8.0_25.

**After a test to 64-bit app:**
the garbage collector as i have tested just dont deallocate the memory it holds 1gb of memory even if i have deleted 5.000.000 buttons.About memory leaks(i just add this buttons to a list and then remove them with the method removeAll() or removeItem() ready by java library).

Thanks!

Comment: The word you are looking for: *Garbage*. ...And GC works, read about it a bit more. Minor/Major GC, what would you need to manage yourself without it, etc.

Comment: Note that neither `free()` nor `delete` guarantees that memory will be returned to the operating system. The purpose of `free`, `delete`, or garbage collection is to allow memory that was used by one object to be re-used by a different object. Java's GC accomplishes that purpose.

Comment: @RealSkeptic  i wanted to make this more realistic :).

Comment: Why do you care?  Are you getting out-of-storage errors??

Comment: @Hot Licks after deleting this items i  want to add other(5000 or more) and the memory goes up to 700 MB and doing this some more times it goes to infinity until it crash.

Comment: If that happens then you have a leak.  Or you're simply allocating too much storage at one time.

Comment: @Hot Licks the second is what i do i am trying to allocate 200-250 MB at once(but i wait 2-3 minutes too check what is going on) but in C/C++ i'ts not problem.

Comment: Has nothing to do with how fast you allocate the storage.  But you can't allocate more than is allowed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the Java garbage collector collect garbage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704589/why-doesnt-the-java-garbage-collector-collect-garbage)

Answer (score 3):

> Why i need Garbage Collector and not a free() method when it doesn't deallocate memory as **needed**?

Because your definition of "needed" and what the JVM thinks is "needed" are two different things. The JVM only *needs* to deallocate memory if it needs to allocate it to something else, and has no free space to give the new objects. On no other occasion is it really *needed*.

Garbage-collecting is there to make your life easier as a programmer, because it is a lot easier to avoid memory leaks when you don't have to do all reference counting that's required for properly freeing space that you have allocated. And this means fewer bugs. But garbage collection is a complicated process, that takes up computing resources, and therefore, it is not activated until the JVM judges that it is worth the effort. (In fact, the decisions are complex, because there are minor and major garbage collections, and different areas of the heap that are deallocated using different considerations).

Your program is not going to allocate more and more memory until it blows up (unless you do have a memory leak). I have Java programs running for months without stopping and they don't blow up despite creating millions of objects per minute sometimes. When it needs to, it will run the garbage collector. Your belief that it should happen as soon as possible is unfounded.

Note that running a garbage collection **does not mean that Java is necessarily returning the memory to the operating system**. It usually keeps it to itself, in case you are going to want to allocate more objects. It has some tuning parameters that tell it when to return memory to the operating system, and it consults those parameters after garbage collection is run. Please read the [tuning guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/index.html) if you are interested.

Comment: nice answer.I undersand that my java Program will blow up when the maximum memory is allocated.The user who will use the app may have 1 gb ram and when the memory reach this(blow up),even if the proggram has 5 items and not 5.000.000 that needs to reach this memory.

Comment: No, it will not blow up. As soon as it sees that it doesn't have any more memory, it will run garbage collection.

Comment: nice here the garbage collector as i have tested just dont deallocate the memory  it holds 1gb of memory even if i have deleted 5.000.000 buttons.About memory leaks(i just add this button to a list and then remove them with the method removeAll() or removeItem() ready by java library).

Comment: That simply means that the JVM didn't consider it necessary to return the memory to the OS. I added some information to my answer. But really, the bottom line is: the JVM will deal with the memory according to its needs, and the program will not run out of memory.

Comment: thanks for reply.Right know i edited my question with a test i did right know.Although i removed all the buttons the memory is still 1.074,4 MB Ok with that.But now i added 50 buttons and the memory gone 1.096,4 MB and not using the actual memory that it has been  allocated before.It is bad it want all the memory for itself!